# Sonar Scanner does not detect project directory for Xcode

Tags: xcode, sonarqube, sonarscanner

I was following [this](https://manoyahavan.medium.com/sonarqube-integration-in-ios-swift-objective-c-developer-edition-9fa5d4bf4e37) tutorial to implement sonarQube and scan my Xcode project.

All is good until I run the scan on my code. It is only detecting one folder of my project.

```
# Sonar Server details
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
sonar.login=admin
sonar.password=Test123.
sonar.token=******TOKEN******
sonar.projectKey=MARi
#sonar.projectName=MARi
# defaults to ‘not provided’
#sonar.projectVersion=1.0
# Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Defaults to .
sonar.sources=.
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
# Xcode project configuration (.xcodeproj)
# and use the later to specify which project(s) to include in the analysis (comma separated list)
# Specify either xcodeproj or xcodeproj + xcworkspace
sonar.swift.project=MARi.xcodeproj
sonar.swift.workspace=MARi.xcworkspace
# Scheme to build your application
sonar.swift.appScheme=MARi Zeta
sonar.swift.appConfiguration=Debug
# Destination Simulator to run surefire
# As string expected in destination argument of xcodebuild command
# Example = sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=12.0
sonar.swift.simulator=platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 14 Pro Max,OS=16.2

sonar.language=swift
#sonar.inclusions=**/*Test*/**
#sonar.inclusions=**/.swift/**/*
sonar.coverage.inclusions=**/*.swift, **/*.swiftmodule
sonar.projectBaseDir=../
#sonar.exclusions=**/*.xml,Pods/**/*,Reports/**/*,ApolloCodegen/**
sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/Pods/**/*,**/ApolloCodegen/**/*
# Path to test directories (comment if no test)
# sonar.tests=testTests,testUITests
```

I have tried many variations of inclusions and exclusions but the result remains the same.
Only the ApolloCodegen folder is scanned. The scan never goes into MARi project.

This is my project heirarchy:

[image: This is my project heirarchy]

I could be missing something as simple as syntax error but the scan executes successfully.

This is the scanner response:

[image: This is the scanner response]

The lines are always 5.2k. Never once more than that. And all the errors are from `ApolloCodegen` folder where infact I want to exclude `ApolloCodegen` and `pods`.

Let me know if any further information is required.

I have tried every variation for inclusions and exclusions I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today and it turned out that you can configure the same properties in the web interface of sonar and there I found a different value. For me it looks like that what config comes from the sever is always applied, nevertheless what you have said in the file.